# how to create function block parameter window settings for my subsystem block?

Tags: simulink

or a simulink project, I created a subsystem, how to create function block parameter window settings for my subsystem block?

[image]

Comment: Check this out https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/design-custom-interface-using-masking.html

Comment: You need to create what is called a Masked Subsystem.  The link given by RatHat shows how to do this.